# Angular2/Nativescript: How to Highlight the selected item of a ListView?

Tags: css, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

i've read through the Nativescript ListView documentation and searched Google and can't find any way to highlight the currently selected item of a Listview...  Is this even possible?  If so how can I go about it?

My code:

```
<ListView [items]="activeStockTakes" class="list-group" (itemTap)="selectActiveStockTake($event)">
                    <template let-activeStockTake="item">
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label class="list-group-item" [text]="activeStockTake.UserCode + ' - ' + activeStockTake.Comment"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </template>
                </ListView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, which Eddy's answer helped me to solve.

2 css classes: Selected and Unselected.

Get the listview element index by adding let-i="index" to the template.

Set the default class with class="Unselected"

Use a data binding to conditionally change the class of the selected listview item [class.Selected]="i===selectedIndex"

Feed the index of the selected element to the component with (tap)="selectMenu(i)"

In your component, create the variable selectedIndex and set it equal to the index of the selected element.

Tapping an element will now change its CSS class. If you have one element selected and tap a different element from the list, the new element will become selected and the first selection will become unselected.

CSS

```
    <ListView [items]="submenu">
        <template let-item="item" let-i="index">
            <Label [class.Selected]="i===selectedIndex" [text]="item" class="Unselected" (tap)="selectMenu(i)"></Label>
        </template>
    </ListView>
```

TS

```
selectedIndex: number;

selectMenu(i) {
    this.selectedIndex=i;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much i've given up on this long ago!!!  Works perfectly:)  One thing I noticed in your code:  why in the function where you set this.selectedIndex do you first copy the value of i to the variable index and not just use i to set selectedIndex?  Thanks again!!!

Comment: My app uses the 2 variables for different things, when I stripped away my non-relevant code for the answer I forgot to take away one of them.  Glad I could help!

Answer (score 6):

Sure you can!

Define a class "highlight" in CSS:

```
.highlight {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

Then assign it based on a condition in the view:

```
<StackLayout [class.highlight]="selectedItem && activeStockTake.UserCode === selectedItem.UserCode">
```

That `selectedItem` property is defined in your Component and assigned/updated when an item is picked in the list.

Comment: that doesn't work for me for some reason...  I have a function in my component selectActiveStockTake(args) which sets the selectedActiveStockTake every time a item gets tapped in the listView so I replaced selectedItem in your code with selectedActiveStockTake...  Am I understanding this correctly?  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: i'm Using the ccore-dark theme so maybe that's overriding the highlight class?  I tried adding !important but doesn't change at all.  It seems like it is working as there's no errors but it just doesn't display for some reason...